# SQL Server : DATETIME to INT

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, google-cloud-ai

The date I have is 10.01.2022, the value I want is 10012022 - how can I do that? Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Why not store the value as a `date`? It is a date after all. Neither `varchar` or `int` are suitable data types for storing date and/or time data.

Comment: Do you mean you have a datetime value and want to convert it to an int in that specific format ? Or is it the opposite ?

Comment: Is that October 1st or January 10th? See why ambiguous, regional formats are bad?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `DateTime` value and want to convert it to an `int` value with that format, you could cast it to varchar first using a format that gets you close, and then get rid of any unwanted symbols, and then convert to int

```
declare @d date = '20220110'
select convert(int, replace(convert(varchar, @d, 103), '/', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this...

```
Select  Day(YourColumn) * 1000000 + Month(YourColumn) * 10000 + Year(YourColumn)
From    YourTable
```

It's not clear from your question if you want month-day-year or day-month-year. Regardless, with this code it should be fairly easy to adjust it to meet your situation.

PS. This will be faster than converting to varchar and then to int.